# I Want to write a subquery to Sum a column

Tags: sql

This query returns the results below.

```
Select BookTitle,TotalNumberInStock 
From CurrentStock
Where (Year<2000 OR Year >2010);
```

**Table 1**

```
BookTitle               TotalNumberInStock
The Tower               2
Orange Goblins          1
The future of Metal     3
Chronicles of the Banjo 2
Opera                   4
Advanced SQL            5
The GAA                 4
```

I want to write a subquery that sums the TotalNumber In Stock so I used this statement:

```
Select Sum(TotalNumberInstock)
From 
(
   Select BookTitle,TotalNumberInStock 
   From CurrentStock
   Where (Year<2000 OR Year >2010)
);
```

I get an error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: There is no need to use the ";" at the end, just add alias like, >2010)) abcd

Comment: Why are you selecting 2 columns in your subselect when you only use one of them in your main select?

Comment: And why are you doing a sub select? Seems like a waste of resources. Just include the where clause in your original statement.

Comment: What do you want the final output to look like?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks Lads. I was using a sub query as i need to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give an alias name to your sub query (aka derived table)

```
select Sum(TotalNumberInstock) 
From (Select BookTitle,TotalNumberInStock From CurrentStock
        Where (Year<2000 OR Year >2010)) x ;
```

this correction makes your query work, but you don't need such complexity to have your desired result. you can simply get what you want by this query

```
select sum(totalNumberInStock)
from CurrentStock
where year < 2000 or year > 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a sub query.

```
select sum(totalNumberInStock)
from CurrentStock
where year < 2000 or year > 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Select BookTitle,SUM(TotalNumberInStock) 
   From CurrentStock
   Where (Year < 2000 and YEAR > 2010)
   GROUP BY BookTitle
```

Comment: He wants books before 2000 or after 2010. `Between` won't do that.

Comment: Also, grouping by `BookTitle` is unnecessary because he already has a total for each book, meaning there is only one record per book title.  In fact selecting the `BookTitle` at all seems unnecessary.

Comment: your query will return the stock amount for every booktitle, but op didn't mentioned he need the stocks for each of them

Comment: If he want to sum all stocks of all books he can use any answer above, if he want to sum the total of each title he can use mine. Relax guys.